# Ruby 1.8.7 extend constant in another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to extend an existing module (namely Redmine::MimeType) by adding a few items to a constant `MIME_TYPES` Hash.

This is what I tried so far and that only gives me a "dynamic constant assignment" error:

```
module MimeTypePatch
  def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
    base.extend(ClassMethods)

    base.class_eval do
      MIME_TYPES_VIDEO = {
        'video/x-flv' => 'flv,f4v',
        'video/mpeg' => '*.mpeg *.mpg *.mpe',
        'video/quicktime' => 'qt,mov',
        'video/vnd.vivo' => 'viv,vivo',
        'video/x-msvideo' => 'avi'
      }.freeze

      # merge the new mime types with the existing ones
      MIME_TYPES = MIME_TYPES.merge(MIME_TYPES_VIDEO).freeze

      EXTENSIONS = MIME_TYPES.inject({}) do |map, (type, exts)|
        exts.split(',').each {|ext| map[ext.strip] = type}
        map
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So what am I doing wrong and what might be the correct approach to alter an existing constant in another module? I do see that changing a constant at runtime is a bit off, but I couldn't think of a more elegant approach to achieve what I want (detecting video mime types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't assign a value to constant after initial definition, you have to create a new constant which will have the merged hash value. Change this line from

```
# merge the new mime types with the existing ones
MIME_TYPES = MIME_TYPES.merge(MIME_TYPES_VIDEO).freeze
```

to

```
# merge the new mime types with the existing ones
MERGED_MIME_TYPES = MIME_TYPES.merge(MIME_TYPES_VIDEO).freeze
```

and then you can use this new constant `MERGED_MIME_TYPES` in further logic

Comment: Kind of... I didn't really want to use this solution though, as I did not want to overwrite / duplicate some methods from redmine. I ended up simply adding my values to the core Hash. Seems a better solution in that case. But thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the freezing, you can *modify* existing constants in many cases rather than trying to redefine them.  For instance, in your example using `#merge!` rather than `#merge` would alter the constant in place.  I'm not sure whether you'd have to take steps to distinguish the definition in the current scope from that in the inherited one (*i.e.*, you don't want to change any ancestry-upstream values of `MIME_TYPES` if there are any).

```
MIME_TYPES = {} unless (defined?(MIME_TYPES))
MIME_TYPES.merge!(MIME_TYPES_VIDEO)
```

Also of interest is the `#replace` method for `Hash`, `Array`, and others:

```
MIME_TYPES.replace(MIME_TYPES.merge(MIME_TYPES_VIDEO))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem however, as you mentioned, is that the Hash in question is frozen. So neither `#merge!` nor `#replace` do work in that context.